# why to remove the state of page while navigation from one page to another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery mobile in my project. I have one div(having some content) in which I set font size. But when I go back and come again it shows the unaltered font size(in div contents). I think it is using caching. How to remove caching in android using jQuery mobile? Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/vfJSQ/).

Do the following steps

1. Click the cancel button. It shows the next page.
2. Click the first button on header it shows slider, then slide the slider and it zooms the content.
3. Then click the second button it closes the screen.
4. Click again cancel button it show same state (zoom state)
5. How can I remove that state?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.CancelSettingButton_h', function(event) {
    //   event.stopPropagation();
    $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.stop_h', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"),{transition:'none'});
});

$(document).on('click', '.follow_h', function() {
    $(".sliderContend_h").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at following code .. i think i have your updated your fiddle but i am not sure

```
$(document).on('click', '.CancelSettingButton_h', function(event) {
       //   event.stopPropagation();



   $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"));

});
$(document).on('click', '.stop_h', function() {
/* new code */
    $('body *').removeClass('font');
/* new code */    
   $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"),{transition:'none'});
});

$(document).on('click', '.follow_h', function() {


   $(".sliderContend_h").toggle("slow");
});

$(document).on('slidestop', '#slider-2', function() {

var style;
    var font = $(this).val();

    if ($('head').find('style.font').length === 0) {
        style = $('<style class="font">.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }</style>');
        $('head').append(style);
        $('#realTimeContents').addClass('font');
    } else {
        $('body *').removeClass('font');
        $('style.font').empty();
        style = '.font { font-size: ' + font + 'px !important; }';
        $('style.font').append(style);
        $('#realTimeContents').addClass('font');
    }
});
**strong text**
```